# How do I create a separate namespace for eval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following code:

```
code = "def hi; \"hi!\"; end"
eval code

hi == "hi!" # true
```

I can access the method `hi`, because when it is defined in the evaluated code, it is defined as a method of the main object.

However, this also means that the evaluated code can access things I define outside of it:

```
def hi; "hi!"; end
eval "hi == \"hi\"" # => true
```

I want to have a separate namespace in which I can run evaluated code; How would I do it?

I tried playing with `module_eval` and using a module for the namespace, but I can't get it to define a method or a class and access that in another evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate code inside of an object like this:

```
  module DSL
    def helper_method_to_be_used_by_evaled_code
      # ...
    end

    # ...
  end

  container = Object.new
  container.extend(DSL)
  File.open(eval_file1, 'r') {|f| container.instance_eval(f.read, eval_file1)}
  File.open(eval_file2, 'r') {|f| container.instance_eval(f.read, eval_file2)}
```

With this you can control whether to preserve definitions between evals or not: you can reuse `container` instance or dispose it and create new one. This would work with method definitions and constants, local variables aren't preserved between such calls.

Also, instead of `Object` you may want to look at `BlankState` pattern. "[blankslate](https://github.com/masover/blankslate)" is an example.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you're talking about making the module part of the evaluated code, so something like this should work just fine:

```
module EvalMethods
  class << self
    code = "def hi; \"hi!\"; end"
    eval code
  end
end

puts EvalMethods::hi == "hi!"
```

Comment: I need to be able to then perform a second eval in which I can access any previous definitions.. how could I do that?